# Bing image services stopped working in Silverlight

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, bing-maps, silverlight

I have been using the Bing image and street services for several years with great success.  However today the services have gone down.  Did I miss the memo about them going away?  Or are they experiencing technical difficulties?  I have switched my app to use ESRI data instead for the time being.

Comment: They [Microsoft] are dropping silverlight as a default when windows 10 (edge browser) 29th July 2015 is released. see http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/02/moving-to-html5-premium-media/ this might be a good time for an alternative to be planned.

Comment: Bing Maps is revamped http://www.technobuffalo.com/2015/07/06/bing-maps-redesign-makes-a-case-to-ditch-google-maps/  see the preview http://www.bing.com/mapspreview/signup

Comment: IE 11 for Windows 10 will still support Silverlight.  That being said, I am currently in the process of redesigning and programming a new app for our department using ESRI's JavaScript api.  Very sad to see Silverlight go though, it was a pretty wonderful platform and excellent api from ESRI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company uses bing maps API for geocoding and map tiles.  It would appear the Bing API was returning 404 for requests for the past several hours.  It just came back up, roughly 5 minutes ago.

You may want to try again.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the reply.  I noticed that it was back up yesterday afternoon as well.